# how to set form border thickness

Tags: vb.net, winforms, windows-7-x64

I am writing an app using VB.net in VB2013. The Sizeable border is too thick in when displayed on PC's with later versions of Windows7, Windows 8(.1).

Does anyone know how to change the thickness of the window?

Comment: is this winform, WPF,....? Please add appropriate tag.

Answer (score 1):

You don't get to control that. That's part of the user theme, and users can set any theme they want. You'll find it's also a problem on older versions of Windows if users have a theme with a wider border. You'll need to adjust your program's layout to allow for a little less space.

Answer (score 0):

The border is drawn by the operating system, but you can create your own custom form, there is a library on CodePlex may help you to do what you need easily.

[Drawing Custom Borders in Windows Forms](http://customerborderform.codeplex.com/)

[image: Drawing Custom Borders in Windows Forms]